# Join issue with Two tables

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have two tables one is called project_table and another one called investment table.

**project_table:**

```
project_id               
project_name  
project_location         
project_phase        
project_capital      
project_total 
project_notes 
project_file
```

**investment table:**

```
id  
project_id 
investor_id     
investment
```

**user table:**

```
user_id
user_name
user_email
user_pass
user_role
user_phone
```

I'm storing the investment from user in a table (investment) and linking that table to project table using project_id

**What i need:**
Display Invested project data from a user. Means if a user login to admin they only need see they project which they have invested, Don't need to display all projects. A user may have option to invest in multiple projects.
So basically if James login to admin he only need see project which have investment from James.

**My function for this is:**

```
public function list_all_projects_by_userid ($uid,$investor){

    $investors = DB::fetch('SELECT * FROM  project_table JOIN investment on project_table.project_id = investment.project_id;  ORDER BY project_id DESC');
   return $investors;   


        }
```

Buts its not working, Please help me. i am using a Extended PDO class which have a fetch method.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this!

```
SELECT * FROM  project_table t JOIN investment i on t.project_id = i.project_id where t.project_name='john' ORDER BY project_id DESC;
```

You placed a **";"** before ORDER BY which is wrong. I guess that the above query would do the trick.

you have to pass the

> project_name='john'

as per your requirement.

for that you need to make connection between usertable and project_table.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your query. Pl try this:

```
SELECT * FROM  project_table JOIN investment on project_table.project_id = investment.project_id  ORDER BY project_id DESC;
```

If your Join criteria is not meeting, pl explain your functionality in detail.

Comment: Its look systax ok now. Thak you but its not getting what i required.

Comment: Yes. I figured out the same. Is your investor_id in "investment" table a foreign key for user_id in "user" table. In that case, you will have to try out something like: SELECT * FROM project_table JOIN investment on project_table.project_id = investment.project_id LEFT OUTER JOIN user ON user.user_id = investment.investor_id ORDER BY project_id DESC;

Comment: @ I want get all project which current logged user invested. I am passing two variable to this function but i dont how make this work : is this possible by passing only one value? I know the current logged user ID list_all_projects_by_userid ($uid) ?

Comment: No i dont set it like but i am sure i am storing it like that. I am storing  investor_id its same as user_id in user table

Comment: investor_id  is have relation with user_id in user table

Comment: Then "SELECT * FROM project_table JOIN investment on project_table.project_id = investment.project_id LEFT OUTER JOIN user ON user.user_id = investment.investor_id ORDER BY project_id DESC;" should work for you.

Comment: method you provided is getting an error Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'project_id' in order clause is ambiguous

Comment: Yes because we did not specify from which table the order by column has to be picked up. Use this - ""SELECT * FROM project_table JOIN investment on project_table.project_id = investment.project_id LEFT OUTER JOIN user ON user.user_id = investment.investor_id ORDER BY project_table.project_id DESC;"

Comment: the query is ok but how i pass current loged user ID to this and use that with this SQL query? Possible?

Comment: In the query, you can achieve this by adding a where clause at the end of your query. Something like "SELECT * FROM project_table JOIN investment on project_table.project_id = investment.project_id WHERE investment.investor_id = $uid ORDER BY project_table.project_id DESC;". The second join wont be required in this case since you already have the user ids stored in investor ids.

Comment: thank you very much it work now :)  public function list_all_projects_by_userid ($uid) {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM project_table JOIN investment on project_table.project_id = investment.project_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.user_id = investment.investor_id WHERE users.user_id = $uid ORDER BY project_table.project_id DESC;";
    $investors = DB::fetch($sql);
    return $investors; 
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the ';' behind the whole query:

```
SELECT *
FROM  project_table JOIN investment
   on project_table.project_id = investment.project_id
ORDER BY project_id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

since invester is an user so function doesn't need two arguments,so i kept it simple

```
public function list_all_projects_by_userid ($uid){
$sql="select * from investment_table Inner Join project_table
on project_table.project_id=investment_table.project_id
where investment_table='".$uid."' ORDER BY investment_table.project_id DESC";
$investors = DB::fetch($sql);
return $investors; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but its show an error Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'project_id' in order clause is ambiguous'

Answer (score 0):

In your function you put semi colon before the order by.

project_id present in both the tables. so you should mention in which table you need to set order by for project_id.

public function list_all_projects_by_userid ($uid,$investor){

```
$investors = DB::fetch('select * from investment_table, project_table where project_table.project_id=investment_table.project_id  ORDER BY investment_table.project_id DESC');
```

return $investors;
        }